# Cant get combobox objects to appear

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Hi in my combobox i want different countries to appear in it. But i try and try and never gets it to appear. This is how i have done:

```
class Countries
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Countries> Cities { get; set; }

    public Countries()
    {
    }
    public Countries(string _name)
    {
        Cities = new List<Countries>();
        Name = _name;

        List<Countries> countries = new List<Countries> { new Countries("UK"),  
                                 new Countries("Australia"),  
                                 new Countries("France") };
   }

   private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        CustomerFiles.Countries country = new CustomerFiles.Countries();
        cbCountry.DataSource = country.Cities;
        cbCountry.DisplayMember = country.Name;
   }
```

What can i do i still dont get any countries inside the combobox?!?

Comment: The code you have provided looks quite unusual - is Countries a windows form class? And why are you setting the combobox datasource in the combobox selected index changed event? Also the display member property for a combobox selectes the proprety of the databound type to display, which doesn't appear to be how you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have provided doesn't make a great deal of sense, with a class Countries which contains a list of the same class and then has the name property. (I'm a little surprised it all compiles)

I'm going to give two basic examples of providing data to a combobox in WinForms - the first simply providing a list of strings and the second databinding against a list of objects (which I suspect is your goal).

Below is a Form class which has a ComboBox member. I create a List and provide the country names which then appear in the ComboBox:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<string> countries_;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        countries_ = new List<string> { "UK",   
                                "Australia",   
                                "France" };

        comboBox1.DataSource = countries;

    }
}
```

The next example is very similar except now I bind to a list of type Country where Country is a class with an id (possibly from a database) and a name. I set the display member to tell the combobox what class property to show the user, and set the value member to the id property to allow me to set the SelecteValue.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool click = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Country> countries = new List<Country> { new Country{ CountryId = 1, Name = "UK"},  
                                new Country{ CountryId = 2, Name = "Australia"},   
                                new Country{ CountryId = 3, Name = "France"} };

        comboBox1.DataSource = countries;
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        comboBox1.ValueMember = "CountryId";
        comboBox1.SelectedValue = 2;
    }
}

public class Country
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to call DataBind method

```
 cbCountry.DataSource = country.Cities;
 cbCountry.DisplayMember = country.Name;

 cbCountry.DataBind(); // method is absent in WinForms
```

Update: your problem is not with databinding - you can fill *cbCountry.DataSource* in your Form constructor. Your Countries.Cities property is empty.

Comment: on "cb.Country.DisplayMember = country.Cities" i get this error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<CustomerRegister1.CustomerFiles.Countries>' to 'string'

and on "cbCountry.Databind();" i get this error: Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.DataBindings' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: With cb.Country.DisplayMember = country.Cities - my fault (incorrectly copied code)

Comment: The winforms combobox does not have a DataBind method. You are thinking of webforms.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `default constructor` of Countries class in your SelectedIndexChanged event. So, the behaviour seems natural to me, since Cities list doesn't contain any item. Don't you need to call your `parameterized constructor` to fill your collection?

Comment: In your SelectionChanged event you are creating an object as - CustomerFiles.Countries country = new CustomerFiles.Countries();
Don't you need to call like this -
CustomerFiles.Countries country = new CustomerFiles.Countries("CountryName");